# gm imagemagick passing in convert arguments as a string

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, imagemagick, gm

I'm trying to pass the convert arguments as string to in() without success.

works fine if I run this:

```
const GM = require('gm');
const gm = GM.subClass({ imageMagick: true });

gm(buf).command('convert').in('-resize','800x','-resize','800x','-sharpen','0x.4','-crop','160x180+0+0','+repage','-quality','92').toBuffer((err, buffer) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(buffer));
```

But not if I run:

```
    const GM = require('gm');
    const gm = GM.subClass({ imageMagick: true });

    let command = "'-resize','800x','-resize','800x','-sharpen','0x.4','-crop','160x180+0+0','+repage','-quality','92'";
    gm(buf).command('convert').in(command).toBuffer((err, buffer) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(buffer));
```

seems to just ignore the command altogether.

The reason I'm attempting to pass the command as a string is that I ultimately want to pass the command to lambda node as an event. ie "event.command"

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem recently. [aws-lambda-image](https://github.com/ysugimoto/aws-lambda-image) is used to process images on the Lambda function. It and the [underlying ImageMagick library](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm) do not support every capability of ImageMagick. In GraphicMagic for node, you have to build a chain of operators as shown [in this example](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm/issues/655#issuecomment-411481724).

However, as in your situation, we may have very complex queries and we don't want to add a new operator for every different query. Therefore, I wrote [a converter](https://gist.github.com/farukcankaya/5b698044d907fe80a7c1f6e3afe618bc#file-imagemagick_command_to_graphicsmagick_converter-js) that converts raw imagemagick `convert` query into GM's chain of operators. It works like below:

```
// Initiate GM
let img = gm(image).limit("memory", `${getEnableMemory()}MB`);
let imageToConvert = img.command("convert");

// Generate operators
let operationAndParameters = parseArgsStringToArgv(command);
let operatorIndexes = findIndexOfOperators(operationAndParameters);
let operators = generateOperators(operatorIndexes, operationAndParameters);

// Apply operators to the image dynamically
operators.forEach(o => imageToConvert.out(o.operator, ...o.parameters));
```

You can also create [ImageConverter](https://gist.github.com/farukcankaya/5b698044d907fe80a7c1f6e3afe618bc#file-imageconverter-js) like [ImageResizer](https://github.com/ysugimoto/aws-lambda-image/blob/master/lib/ImageResizer.js) to use in your [aws-lambda-image](https://github.com/ysugimoto/aws-lambda-image) function. In this case, only you need to do is:

```
let command = "'-resize','800x','-resize','800x','-sharpen','0x.4','-crop','160x180+0+0','+repage','-quality','92'";
const converter = new ImageConverter(params)
converter.exec(image)
```

Check my gist to see the script: https://gist.github.com/farukcankaya/5b698044d907fe80a7c1f6e3afe618bc